# Azure Conditional Access can't Include or Exclude users

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Basically my problem can be seen on this picture :
[azure conditional access error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2R1Y.png)

When I go to Conditional Access > Assignments, I have red crosses both on Include and Exclude users or groups. My account has Global Administrator role assigned and the tenant has O365 E1 plus EMS E5 licenses. What must I do to enable the option to Include or Exclude users and groups in the Conditional Access policies?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Access is not supported with **O365 E1 license**, this feature requires **`Azure AD Premium P1 license`**.

- ***Azure AD Premium P1 license*** is included as part of Enterprise Mobility and Security **(EM+S) E3** and Microsoft 365 E3.
- ***Azure AD Premium P2 license*** is included as part of Enterprise Mobility and Security **(EM+S) E5** and Microsoft 365 E5. So, even if you have **EMS E5 license**  you may face difficulty in creating conditional access policy.

Otherwise, you should have **[Microsoft 365 Business Premium license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-service-descriptions-technet-library)** which includes a subset of **Azure AD Premium P1** that supports Conditional Access.

I have ***Microsoft 365 Business Premium license*** and I tested in my environment where I am able to include or exclude users successfully.

[image]

So, for the workaround, make use of **Microsoft 365 Business Premium license** and try.

> **Note:**  While creating Conditional Access policies, Microsoft recommends to
> exclude the **Global Administrator** group from your Conditional
> Access policies to save yourself from losing access(lockout) to Azure.

Please find below links if they are helpful.

**References:**

[What is Conditional Access in Azure Active Directory? | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview#license-requirements)

[Conditional Access for Office 365 (enowsoftware.com)](https://www.enowsoftware.com/solutions-engine/conditional-access-for-office-365)

[How to Set Up Conditional Access in Office 365? – TheITBros](https://theitbros.com/conditional-access-office-365/)

##### Update:

As you mentioned in the comment, removing Conditional access permissions will take a while to reflect. Make sure you have **`Security Administrator`** role while doing all these. Good to know that it's working now. Thanks for the update.

Comment: The tenant is showing Azure AD Premium P2 and this is what matters. So it's not a license problem. To update the issue. After adding Security Administrator and Conditional Access permissions and nothing happened, I removed the permissions and again no change. But on the next day I tried again and it was working. No idea how this happened, maybe the permissions needed a refresh. So it's working now, thanks for the replies!